# Extracting best guess first and last names from a string

Tags: r

I have a set of names that looks as such:

```
names <- structure(list(name = c('Michael Smith ♕',
                         'Scott Lewis - Realtor',
                         'Erin Hopkins ≈¶',
                         'Katie Parsons | Denver',
                         'Madison Hollins Taylor',
                         'Kevin D. Williams',
                         '|Ryan Farmer|',
                         'l a u r e n   t h o m a s',
                         'Dave Goodwin',
                         'Candice Harper Makeup Artist',
                         'dani longfeld // millenialmodels',
                         'Madison Jantzen | DALLAS, TX',
                         'Rachel Wallace Perkins',
                         'Kayla Wright Photography',
                         'Scott Green Jr.')), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -15L))
```

In addition to getting first and last name extracted from each of these, for ones like `Rachel Wallace Perkins` and `Madison Hollins Taylor`, I'd like to create one to multiple extracts since we don't really know which is their true last name. The final output would look something like this:

```
names_revised <- structure(list(name = c('Michael Smith',
                                  'Scott Lewis',
                                  'Erin Hopkins',
                                  'Katie Parsons',
                                  'Madison Hollins',
                                  'Madison Taylor',
                                  'Kevin Williams',
                                  'Ryan Farmer',
                                  'Lauren Thomas',
                                  'Dave Goodwin',
                                  'Candice Harper',
                                  'Dani Longfeld',
                                  'Madison Jantzen',
                                  'Rachel Wallace',
                                  'Rachel Perkins',
                                  'Kayla Wright',
                                  'Scott Green')), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -17L))
```

Based on some previous answers, I attempted to do (using the tidyr package):

```
names_extract <- tidyr::extract(names, name, c("FirstName", "LastName"), "([^ ]+) (.*)")
```

But that doesn't seem to do the trick, as the output it produces looks as such:

```
FirstName                    LastName
1    Michael                     Smith ♕
2      Scott             Lewis - Realtor
3       Erin                  Hopkins ≈¶
4      Katie            Parsons | Denver
5    Madison              Hollins Taylor
6      Kevin                 D. Williams
7      |Ryan                     Farmer|
8          l     a u r e n   t h o m a s
9       Dave                   Goodwin
10   Candice        Harper Makeup Artist
11      dani longfeld // millenialmodels
12   Madison        Jantzen | DALLAS, TX
13    Rachel             Wallace Perkins
14     Kayla          Wright Photography
15     Scott                   Green Jr.
```

I know there are a ton of little edge cases that make this difficult, but overall, what would be the best approach for handling this that would capture the most results I'm trying for?

Comment: I think a ton of little edge cases are exactly what you need to deal with. Looking at these, you could get a much better result by (a) removing any leading non-letter characters, and then (b) removing any other non-letter non-space non-dot characters and everything after them (and then trim whitespace). That will clean up rows 1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 9, 11, 12 pretty well. You also need to decide what you want to do with middle initials - removing single letter followed by `.` might make sense to do first.

Comment: But I don't know of a better general solution than to iterate until you're satisfied with the result.

Comment: Thanks. Just curious, what would that look like in the form of an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a first go at cleaning the data - (much) more will be needed to obtain perfect data:

```
library(stringr)
df %>%
  mutate(name = str_extract(name, "[\\w\\s.]+\\w"))
                           name
1                 Michael Smith
2                   Scott Lewis
3                  Erin Hopkins
4                 Katie Parsons
5        Madison Hollins Taylor
6             Kevin D. Williams
7                   Ryan Farmer
8     l a u r e n   t h o m a s
9                  Dave Goodwin
10 Candice Harper Makeup Artist
11                dani longfeld
12              Madison Jantzen
13       Rachel Wallace Perkins
14     Kayla Wright Photography
15               Scott Green Jr
```

Here we use `str_extract`, which extracts just the first match in the string, which is convenient as most of the characters that you want to remove are right-end bound. The character class `[\\w\\s.]+` matches any alphanumeric and whitespace characters and the dot occurring one or more times. It is followed by `\\w`, i.e., a single alphanumeric character to make sure that the extracted parts do not end on whitespace. As said, that's just a first go but the data is already very much tidier.

Answer (score 0):

This fixes most of the rows.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

Names %>%
  mutate(name2 = sub("^[[:punct:]]", "", name) %>%
    sub(" \\w[.] ", " ", .) %>%
    sub("[[:punct:]]+ *[^[:punct:]]*$", "", .) %>%
    sub("\\W+[[:upper:]]+$", "", .) %>%
    trimws) %>%
  separate(name2, c("First", "Last"), extra = "merge")
```

giving:

```
                               name   First                    Last
1                   Michael Smith ♕ Michael                   Smith
2             Scott Lewis - Realtor   Scott                   Lewis
3                   Erin Hopkins ≈¶    Erin                 Hopkins
4            Katie Parsons | Denver   Katie                 Parsons
5            Madison Hollins Taylor Madison          Hollins Taylor
6                 Kevin D. Williams   Kevin                Williams
7                     |Ryan Farmer|    Ryan                  Farmer
8         l a u r e n   t h o m a s       l a u r e n   t h o m a s
9                    Dave Goodwin??    Dave                 Goodwin
10     Candice Harper Makeup Artist Candice    Harper Makeup Artist
11 dani longfeld // millenialmodels    dani                longfeld
12     Madison Jantzen | DALLAS, TX Madison                 Jantzen
13           Rachel Wallace Perkins  Rachel         Wallace Perkins
14         Kayla Wright Photography   Kayla      Wright Photography
15                  Scott Green Jr.   Scott                Green Jr
```